# Retrofit - Parsing generic api response with base class

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

I am using retrofit for rest api calls for my android app development. Since my all api response has `"info"`(Note that all api will have same key name) and `"data"` (**Note that different apis have different key names**) parameter, I have used a base class  for the api responses. Below are the sample responses from API

**Response 1**

```
{
"info":{
        "statusCode":200,
        "message":"OK"
       },
"data":{
        "userId":2,
        "userName":"riyas"
       }
 }
```

**Response 2**

```
{
"info":{
        "statusCode":200,
        "message":"OK"
       },
"data":{
        "vegId":2,
        "vegName":"Potatoa"
       }
 }
```

I have created a base class named **CloudBaseResponse** and was able to get data in **`response.info`** . But I have no idea to parse the `**data**` . Please suggest me  a way to handle using **Retrofit**

```
public class CloudBaseResponse {

   public BaseResponse response;

    public BaseResponse  getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(BaseResponse response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public class BaseResponse {
        public Info info;

    }

    public class Info{
        public String status;
        public String message;
    }

}
```

Comment: are you using Gson to deserialize your response?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `Generics` to map your api response.

```
public class CloudBaseResponse<T> {
    @SerializedName("info")   
    private Info info;    

    @SerializedName("data")
    private T data;

    // Getters Setters..
}  

public class Info {
    private String status;
    private String message;

    // Getters Setters.. 
}
```

For example you have a `Vegetable` class.

```
public class Vegetable {
    private int vegetableId;
    private String vegetableName;

    // Getters Setters..
}
```

Later you can use with `Retrofit` like the following code:

```
Call<CloudBaseResponse<Vegetable>> getVegetables();
```

Comment: What if its a list of  T data coming from API?

Comment: You may create a rgeneric esponse like "CloudBaselistResponse<List<T>>" and handle the response like this. the data should be List<T> data

Comment: I understand. Please see this question I just posted, I have elaborated my concern here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67816386/parsing-nested-polymorphic-objects-with-gson-and-retrofit

Answer (score 3):

Create a class named `BaseModel` and extends it in your response model (data)

```
public class BaseModel {
    Info info;

    public getInfo(){ return info;}
    public setInfo(Info info){ this.info = info; }

    public BaseModel() {
    }
}

public class Info{
    int statusCode;
    String message;

    public int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
}
```

and your data class is like:

```
class Response extends BaseModel {
    public Data data;
}

class Data{
    public int vegId;
    public String vegName;
}
```

And finally, in `Retrofit` you have parse response to `Response` class